# Trying to copy a field of one struct to another struct in c?

Tags: c, struct, compiler-errors, typedef

So I have code for a Connect Four game in C. The struct I'm using right now is:

```
typedef struct {int value; board brd; } state ;
typedef char board[8][8] ;
#define BOARD(p_S) (((state *) (p_S)->brd)
```

And I'm trying to compile the main function but I continuously get an error on this line:

```
BOARD(&currentstate) = BOARD(p_nextstate) ;
```

where currentstate's type is state and p_nextstate is a pointer to a state. I need to have the board field of current state be changed to match that of p_nextstate, but when I compile I get this error:

```
error: incompatible types when assigning to type "board" from type "char(*)[8]"
```

The full code is way to long to put here, I think I've included all the relative lines but if not I will add them. Is there a correct way to change this line? Any help is appreciated.
EDIT: The missing parenthesis was my mistake, it was in the code but I mistyped it here. It's now fixed to match the code. Here is the full main function:

```
    int main( int argc, char * argv[]){

  tree T ;
  state currentstate, *p_nextstate ;
  int depth ;

  initialize_board(BOARD(&currentstate)) ;
  do{
    printf("Enter game tree depth: ") ;
    scanf("%d", &depth) ;
  }while(depth < 1) ;
  print_board(BOARD(&currentstate)) ;

  while(get_move(BOARD(&currentstate), PLAYER) != 0){
    print_board(BOARD(&currentstate)) ;
    if(have_winner(BOARD(&currentstate)) == TRUE){
      printf("You win.\n") ;
      exit(0) ;
    }

    printf("Calculating my move...\n") ;
    init_tree(&T) ;
    if(make_state_root(&T, currentstate, NULL, NULL) == ERROR){
      printf("Memory Allocation error in move().\n") ;
      exit(-1) ;
    }

    printf("Board is now:\n") ;
    print_board(BOARD(p_nextstate)) ;
    printf("Minimax value is %d\n", VALUE(p_nextstate)) ;
    if(have_winner(BOARD(p_nextstate)) == TRUE){
      printf("I win.\n") ;
      exit(0) ;
    } else if (VALUE(p_nextstate) == WIN){
    printf("I concede.\n") ;
    exit(0) ;
       }
     BOARD(&currentstate)  =  BOARD(p_nextstate) ;
     destroy_tree(&T, free) ;
   }

   return 0 ;
    }
```

Comment: Try switching the order of the two typedefs and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Macros are basically just copy and paste substitutions. Try substituting it and see what code you get.

```
((state *) (&currentstate)->brd) = ((state *) (p_nextstate)->brd);
```

Edit: Nevermind, you fixed the macro

I think the problem might be that your definition of `board` wasn't defined at the point where you defined your struct, so it thinks that your `brd` member is supposed to have some other type named `board`. Try switching the order of the two typedefs and see if that helps.

Comment: I've switched the typedefs around, but I'm still getting the same error. At that line p_nextstate and &currentstate should be the same type, I can't figure out why p_nextstate is being read as a char*[8]

Comment: That's very strange. Could you post a minimal code example demonstrating the problem?

Comment: That was really the only line were the error occurred, but I'll post the entire main function if it can be of any use.